# Angular validation to allow specific special characters

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript, validation

How do we design the regex to allow characters and numbers and allow special character but only - and dot(.) and ignore or do not allow other special characters

#Code

```
private _createModelForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      propertyId: this.data.propertyId,
      folderName: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/)
      ]),
      documentManagementFolderId:this.data.documentManagementFolderId
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is untested but something like this might work `^([\w\d\-]{1,})([\.])?([\w\d]{1,})$`.  Basically is (1 or more character, digit or hyphen) (optional dot (.)), (followed by 1 or more character or digit).

Comment: I tested does not work Sir ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with some special syntax like: `[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+.`?
I mean put the `\` before the special character you want to allow.
[https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html#:~:text=Special%20Regex%20Characters%3A%20These%20characters,E.g.%2C%20%5C](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html#:%7E:text=Special%20Regex%20Characters%3A%20These%20characters,E.g.%2C%20%5C).